# How to change Javascript code at runtime?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Javascript can write on HTML pages, and change an HTML element's content, but can we use Javascript to change particular text?  I want to change a variable with its value, not in the server but in the client.

I'm working with a JS library, which is Chart.js, knowing that charts must (I hope not necessary) be fed with values from server, but I want to push values from a JSON object, which is a server response.

Comment: Yes, you can change text with javascript. You need to access the Document Object Model. Perhaps in response to an event. I think you should probably start by purchasing a book on JavaScript.

Comment: just change the variable's value: `varname = newvalue`. you don't need to re-write the actual JS code.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem here, I don't want to assign values!, I want to change the script itself for example <script> foo </script> to <script >bar</script> by another script at the bottom of the page

Comment: Many down votes! please explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution to my own problem, the JS library chart.js now accepts data "dynamically ".

Now back to whether Javascript can modify its code?, no it ***can't mutate it's existing code***, but more instructions / functions can be ***added and evaluated*** using the eval function.

Quote from Wikipedia:

> JavaScript, allow programs to create new code at run-time and execute it using an eval function, but do not allow existing code to be mutated.

[page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code)

> In JavaScript, eval is something of a hybrid between an expression evaluator and a statement executor. It returns the result of the last expression evaluated.
>   Example as an expression evaluator:
>   foo = 2;
>   alert(eval('foo + 2'));

[page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#JavaScript)

Answer (score -3):

Make sure to set the variable global, not bound locally, and you can change its value anywhere and anytime (after the document has loaded of course).